# How to call a function passed as a string in a json string

Tags: json, swift, closures

I am reading from a backend, a JSON file with parameters which include a function with arguments `{ "function": {"arg1": 45, "arg2": 73}}`. I would like to execute the function using the arguments specified in the JSON string. How would I implement this in Swift 3?

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to call a Swift or JavaScript function?

Comment: Can you show any code you have tried to implement so far, such as the function that makes the call for that JSON? I can edit it once you add it to your question

Comment: You need to use a framework like `SwiftyJSON`  https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON to grab the data you need from the `JSON` format to variables and then add the variables to the function.

Comment: Swift doesn't have the reflection capabilities necessary to create arbitrary invocations of arbitrary functions by their (string) name (yet). At best, you could have a data structure that associates function names (strings) to the functions (closures), with some logic that parses out the parameters and performs the call. However, this whole design seems ill advised. It's not the backends job to tell the client specifically what functions to call.

Comment: Paulo: I am calling a swift function. Stupid example would be to add the two numbers in which case, could I not pass a closure using $1 and $2.

Comment: If all the processing is known in advance, I can implement all the functions and use a string tag to execute the right function. However, I am trying to handle a situation where the processing may need to be modified because of area in which the app is operating. I think, I can do it by passing a closure as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute javascript in an instance of WKWebView and get the result back with [WKWebView.evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript).  You need the actual code for the function though, which I don't see in your sample. You can grab the values of the arguments from the JSON with [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization), SwiftJSON, ObjectMapper or any of the other many JSON libraries.